# Flag missing record between 2 datasets

Tags: sql-server

The Title doesn't quite explain the issue, so I will give an example:

Table 1 (OrderNum, OrderLine) - All OrderLines ever created.
Table 2 (OrderNum, OrderLin) - Order Lines to be printed right now.

Table 2 always has matches in Table 1 as it is populated from table 1, but sometimes is missing a Line from an order in Table 1.  For instance:

Table 1:

```
OrderNum, OrderLine
100, 1
100, 2
100, 3
100, 4
101, 1
102, 1
102, 2
```

Table 2:

```
OrderNum, OrderLine
100, 1
100, 2
100, 4
101, 1
```

In this instance I need to print all 4 lines of Order 100, with Line 3 flagged as missing, and all of Order 101, but none of order 102.  Obviously my tables are much larger than this, but this sums up my dilemma. I cannot control how either table is populated.

If I LEFT Join Table 2 to Table 1 on OrderNum and OrderLine, then i get OrderNum 102 as well and I don't want that.  If I Join on OrderNum Only then I get dupes of Order 100 for every line in Table 2, how do i find the 1 record not-duped?

Hope that makes sense as to my issue.  I have tried Googling, but the terms are so generic I get way to many irrelevant results.

Comment: You should use table1LEFT JOIN Table2 on both the columns OrderNum and OrderLine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a `left join` and `exists()`:

```
select
    t1.OrderNum
  , t1.OrderLine
  , Missing = case when t2.OrderLine is null then 'Flag' else '' end
from t1
  left join t2
    on t1.OrderNum = t2.OrderNum
   and t1.OrderLine = t2.OrderLine
where exists (
    select 1
    from t2 i
    where t1.OrderNum = i.OrderNum
    )
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/SZPX33524

returns:

```
+----------+-----------+---------+
| OrderNum | OrderLine | Missing |
+----------+-----------+---------+
|      100 |         1 |         |
|      100 |         2 |         |
|      100 |         3 | Flag    |
|      100 |         4 |         |
|      101 |         1 |         |
+----------+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: I always forget that Exists can reference the outside query, I knew it once.  Anyway, Thank you, worked perfectly!